# How to set a dependency for a project with all subprojects?

Tags: gradle, dependency-management, project-structure

I don't like that I repeat every repository dependency (let us say, `junit`), for the main project and for subprojects. Is there a possibility to make the subproject to use the dependencies of the main project. Or is there another way to escape that repetition?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

root/build.gradle

```
allprojects {
    if (plugins.hasPlugin('java')) {
        dependencies {
            testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could this be configured for Kotlin?

Comment: Configuration with name 'testCompile ' not found.

Comment: @kylie.zoltan Configurations for compiling got new names starting from Gradle 7.x, `testImplementation` would be the replacement for `testCompile`. https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_6.html#sec:configuration_removal

Answer (score 17):

Unlike the accepted answer it's better to use the following:

```gradle
allprojects {
  plugins.withType(JavaPlugin) {
    dependencies {
      testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }
  }
}
```

The changes will be applied immediately if `java` plugin already exists or will watch for it to be added and apply later.

**Updated**

At the moment I use better way to control configuration for plugin - `pluginManager`. The effect is the same as for `plugins.withType`, but you don't have to know plugin's class name:

Example for `org.springframework.boot` plugin:

```gradle
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

allprojects {
  pluginManager.withPlugin('org.springframework.boot') {
    springBoot {
      buildInfo()
      layout 'DIR'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that variant. For me, there is no difference in them, for all my subprojects are java ones and I don't use any conditional.